# is Getit package a Dependency injector in flutter?

Tags: flutter

in my opinion, the [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package is one of ways to dependency injection in flutter, is that  so? I'm just not sure about it, please help me figure it out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather not. `get_it` describes itself as a Service Locator, as can be seen it its documentation. A service locator is a different pattern than Dependency Injection, although they can be used for the same purpose.

Both approaches aim towards abstracting object interfaces from their actual implementation, but do it in slightly different ways. In classical dependency injection (e.g. via constructor or interface injection), each object holds a reference to the objects that implements its specific behavior. With the service locator pattern, there is just one single object - `getIt()` in our case - that can be used to find implementations across the whole application.

A great and more extensive discussion of these appraoches can be found in [this article by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection).